# Error installing Rails 3.0.1 (File not found:lib)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rails

I am trying to install rails 3.0.1 on ubuntu 10.10.  I am getting this error towards the end when i execute this command
**sudo gem install rails --version 3.0.1**

> Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
>   File not found: lib

How can i resolve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: For people with this issue here is the entire solution which presents it in a structured way.
http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/How-to-install-Rails-3.0-and-Ruby-1.9.2-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify version number if it is the latest in the repository, just using:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

should work.

If that's a no-go, try manually reinstalling RDoc:

```
sudo gem install rdoc-data
sudo rdoc-data --install
sudo gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```

Comment: Thanks.The first command didn't work out.I executed the commands to manually install rdoc and then used 'apt-get install rails' and then executed gem install rails.
After this when i executed 
'rails -v' 
Rails rails 3.0.4.(I guess this means rails is installed :) )

Comment: @roger thanks for the update, glad it worked for you :)